# Texture paint and UVW doesn't match

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Hi I have tried to draw texture on unwrapped object but it seams that in other then paint mode texture doesn't fit exact place.
Blender v. 2.93.0

Am I doing smth. wrong?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably your mesh has more than one UV Map. You can either delete the unuseful one or specify which UV map your image should use with an UV Map input node in the material node editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your image is being handled by an [Environment Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/environment.html) node, which is generally not meant for texturing objects.

Instead, you should use a [Image Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html) node.